# Detect RDP connection

Tags: remote-desktop

I connect to my PC (Windows XP Pro, which runs 24/7) through RDP on an off through the day.
I have a background process that should do some things upon RDP connection, but I couldn't figure a way to make it detect the establishing of the RDP connection.

No new processes are created, WTSQuerySessionInformation doesn't help (I connect to the same eternal Windows session).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is [`WTSRegisterSessionNotification()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsregistersessionnotification) from [wtsapi32.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/).

This signs you up for receiving [`WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/wm-wtssession-change) notifications, whose `WParam` could be `WTS_REMOTE_CONNECT`, `WTS_REMOTE_DISCONNECT`. That does it.

Here is the simplest AutoIt implementation:

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <Date.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

Global Const $hWTSAPI32 = DllOpen("wtsapi32.dll")
Global $i = 0, $tTime

_Main()

Func _Main()
    Local $hGUI
    
    ; Create GUI
    $hGUI = GUICreate("Session change detection", 600, 400)
;~  GUISetState()  ; show the window
    
    DllCall($hWTSAPI32, "int", "WTSRegisterSessionNotification", "hwnd", $hGUI, "dword", 1) ; NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS
    If @error Then 
        MsgBox(0,"", "Error calling WTSRegisterSessionNotification()")
        Exit
    EndIf
    
    GUIRegisterMsg(0x2B1, "WTSSESSION_CHANGE")  ; WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE <=====================
    
    ; Loop until user exits
    Do
    Until GUIGetMsg() = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
   
EndFunc   ;==>_Main

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Func WTSSESSION_CHANGE($hWndGUI, $MsgID, $WParam, $LParam)
    ; WTS_REMOTE_CONNECT = 0x3, WTS_REMOTE_DISCONNECT = 0x4
    ; WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK = 0x8, WTS_SESSION_LOGON = 0x5
    If $WParam = 3 Then
        $tTime = _Date_Time_GetSystemTime()
        MsgBox(0, "Caught a notification", "Remote session connected at " & _Date_Time_SystemTimeToDateTimeStr($tTime) )
        Exit
    EndIf
EndFunc
```